# Visual Studio Code does not show IntelliSense?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code does not show any IntelliSense when working with react application development. and cannot navigate through files. but it works for other simple application development(eg: NodeJs application). vs code initializing JS/TS language features but it never stops.

what is the issue? how can I solve it?

Comment: it was working with react application and suddenly stopped working? 
are you install a package for VScode that cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to try to solve this issue by installing appropriate Extensions from marketplace.

If it not works download the latest version of [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads)
and reinstall.

You can also refer [React in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial)

Comment: I have worked previously with react in visual studio code. it is not the problem with react specific extension. I could not see any IntelliSense suggestions for Java Script also. all stops when I start typing. eg: consol. does not suggest log() method.

Comment: i.  Open the Command Palette (view menu → command palette)
ii. Enter TypeScript: Restart TS server. (type "restart" and it should auto suggest)